# Can I store HashSet to Firestore document (Java)

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashset

I am retrieving a list from Firestore and checking if it contains a particular string. This list can have thousands of entries. But I have found out the HashSet.contains is much faster than List.contains (sometimes up to 20 times faster). So I'm trying to find out if a HashSet can be saved to Firestore so that searching through the set is faster than searching through a list if it were a list.

From research, I have found that Firestore supports particular data types. I know that Firestore supports Maps and that HashSet uses Maps internally. So does this mean that HashSet is a supported data type?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm trying to find out if a HashSet can be saved to Firestore

As specified in the official documentation regarding [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types):

A `HashSet` is **not** a supported data type.

> So does this mean that HashSet is a supported data type?

It doesn't. There is no way you can save a `HashSet` as a property in a document. You can save it as a `Map` or as an `array` and then convert it to a `HashSet` on the client.